# Why are these regular expressions different?

Tags: regex, grep

I am looking for lines that have an apostrophe in them and tried a few expressions that seemed identical to me; however, some worked and others didn't. Why did I get the following behavior:

```
egrep \' file      # works as expected

egrep "\'" file    # seems to return all lines

egrep "[\']" file  # works as expected

egrep '\'' file    # seems to be waiting for more input
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single vs. double quotes have differences when it comes to escaping.  Put `echo` in front to see what actually gets sent to `egrep`:

```
$ echo egrep \' file
egrep ' file
$ echo egrep "\'" file
egrep \' file
$ echo egrep "[\']" file
egrep [\'] file
$ echo egrep '\'' file
>
```

The last case is prompting for more input because you're still within a single-quoted expression: it's not an escaped quote (`\'`) in single quotes (since that isn't how you escape single quotes.) It's a backslash between single quotes, with a trailing opening quote.

Incidentally, to escape a single quote in a single-quoted string, use a construction like this:

```
$ echo 'foo'\''bar'
foo'bar
```

What this is actually doing is putting a naked literal quote(`\'`) between two single-quoted strings.  These are then all implicitly concatenated together.

I have no idea why `"\'"` matches all lines (but it indeed seems to.)

Comment: your wording is a bit misleading: _escaping with [...] quotes_ sounds like you're _using_ quotes to escape. good suggestion re: using `echo` to sort out what's going on

Comment: How would you escape a character in single quotations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating it, if you're trying to match `'` quote it in `"`:

```
echo "'" | grep "'"
```