# Why does grep match all lines for the pattern "\'"

Tags: regex, grep

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11699078/390913) there is something that I cannot explain:

```
grep "\'" input_file
```

matches all lines in the given file. Does `\'` have a special meaning for grep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[grep regex GNU extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html): ‘\'’ matches the end of the whole input

Answer (score 3):

That is a really strange beaviour of `grep`, I don't know how to explain it, but I must note that `\'` doesn't match any character. It looks like it has the same meaning as `$`:

```
$ echo x | grep "x\'"
x
$ echo xy | grep "x\'"
$ echo x | grep "\'x"
```

**Update 1**

As it is stated in http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html (thanks to Richard Sitze for the link) it really has the same meaning as `$`. But meanwhile I've noted a difference between `\'` and `$`:

```
$ echo x | grep 'x$'
x
$ echo x | grep 'x$$'
$ echo x | grep "x\'"
x
$ echo x | grep "x\'\'"
x
$ echo x | grep "x\'\'\'"
x
```

You can specify `\'` as many times as you wish but that is not so for `$`. There must be only one `$`.

Another important remark. The manual says:

```
 ‘\'’ matches the end of the whole input
```

But strictly speaking that's not truth because `\'` matches not only the end of the whole input but the end of every single line also:

```
$ (echo x; echo y) | grep "\'"
x
y
```

Exactly how `$` does.

Comment: For me `$` and `\'` behave a little differently. `echo x | grep "$x"` matches, but `echo x | grep "\'x"` doesn't match.

Comment: You must write `grep '$x'` not `grep "$x"`; because `"$x"` will be expanded by shell and `"$x"` is the same as `''` (nothing). Just try `echo "$x"` and `echo '$x'`

Comment: Plus `$` has no meaning at the start of a line from an anchoring perspective. Double fail on my part.

Comment: @theon: no, it has meaning, the same meaning as always, but the re will never match

Comment: You said "'\' matches not only the end of the whole input but the end of every single line also".  Did it match the end of each individual line OR did it match the entire input?

Answer (score 3):

I did not know this feature of the regular expressions. But it's listed at regular-expressions.info as the [**end of the string**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) anchor.

It does not exist in all regex implementations only in GNU Basic and Extended Regular Expressions, see this [compatibility chart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

\ is an escape character. This mean the the ' should considered as text to search for, and not as a control character.

Comment: But even if the text file doesn't contain a single quote char, grep still matches all lines in the file. I think that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: yes, it is weird that grep matches all input for literal single quote