# Why does grep matches all the lines no matter what the pattern

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm having a problem using grep.
I have a file http://pastebin.com/HxAcciCa that I want to check for certain patterns. And when I"m trying to search for it grep returns all the lines provided that the pattern already exists in the given file.

To explain more this is the code that I'm running

```
grep -F  "ENVIRO" "$file_pos" >> blah
```

No matter what else I try even if I provide a whole line as a pattern bash always returns all the lines.
These are variations of what I'm trying:

```
grep -F  "E20" "$file_pos" >> blah
grep E20 "$file_pos" >> blah 
grep C:\E20-II\ENVIRO\SSNHapACS480.dll "$file_pos" >> blah
grep -F C:\E20-II\ENVIRO\SSNHapACS480.dll "$file_pos" >> blah
```

Also for some strange reasons when adding the -x option to grep, it doesn't return any line despite the fact that the exact pattern exists.

I've searched the web and the bash documentation for the cause but couldn't find anything.

My final test was the following

```
grep -F -C 1  "E20" "$store_pos" >> blah #store_pos has the same value as $file_pos
```

I thought maybe it was printing the lines after the result but that was not the case.
I was using the blah file to see the output.
Also I'm using Linux mint rebecca.
Finally although the naming is quite familiar this question is not similiar to [Why does grep match all lines for the pattern "\'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699517/why-does-grep-match-all-lines-for-the-pattern)

And finally I would like to say that I am new to bash.
I suspect The error might be due to the main file http://pastebin.com/HxAcciCa rather than the code?

Comment: You're appending to `blah`. Where's the part where you truncate it to be empty?

Comment: Things like `grep -F C:\E20-II\ENVIRO\SSNHapACS480.dll "$file_pos"` can't work, the backslashes need to be escaped or quoted if you want them to be passed to grep. So: `grep -F 'C:\E20-II\ENVIRO\SSNHapACS480.dll' "$file_pos"`. And that can be combined with `-x`. But that problem should have the opposite effect: you should have no matches, rather than every line as a match.

Comment: problem with line endings in the file? check the hexdump or `cat -vET filename`.

Comment: Apparently if I use wc -l I get the count 0, I generated the file that I'm searching for a pattern from an installation log, Then I used grep on the file and generated the file in the question i.e http://pastebin.com/HxAcciCa by putting the output in a file. Is the no newlines due to the fact that the file is from an installation log or from grep?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Apparently each line ends with ^M.

Comment: @robmayoff I was truncating the file manually. i.e deleting the output each time.

Comment: I suspected that the error was from a lack of newlines but seeing as the file contained each file location in pastebin.com/HxAcciCa on a new line I thought maybe it wasn't that.

Comment: What is the value of `$file_pos`? If this is an empty string, then all lines will be matched.

Comment: @alvits its not an empty string it contains the path to the file

Comment: Our speculations about what could be wrong with the file are not going anywhere, but a problem with the file is probably still the reason you don't get the results you expect, and where we need to focus.  Maybe you could explain where this file came from, and perhaps post a hex dump of the first couple of lines.  Common Unix hexdump tools include `od -cH`, `xxd`, and `hexdump`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that the file has carriage returns delimiting the lines, rather than the linefeeds that `grep` expects; as a result, `grep` sees the file as one huge line, that either matches or fails to match as a whole.

(Note: there are at least three different conventions about how to delimit the lines in a "plain text" file -- unix uses newline (`\n`), DOS/Windows uses carriage return followed by newline (`\r\n`), and pre-OSX versions of MacOS used just carriage return (`\r`).)

I'm not clear on how your file wound up in this format, but you can fix it easily with:

```
tr '\r' '\n' <badfile >goodfile
```

or on the fly with:

```
tr '\r' '\n' <badfile | grep ...
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it. One question though why was cat reading the '\r' as ^M rather than '\r'?

Comment: @user1544624: There are a number of different conventions for representing nonprinting characters. `\r` (for "Return") is the C language convention, which is fairly widely used. Others you might run across include `^M` (because carriage return is Control-M in the ASCII code), `<CR>` (for Carriage Return), `\015` (the ASCII character code in octal), and probably others I'm not thinking of offhand.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the line endings in your input file: `file`, `wc -l`.
2. Check you are indeed using the correct `grep`: `which grep`.
3. Use `>` to redirect the output, or `| more` or `| less` to not be confused by earlier attempts you are appending to.

Edit: Looks like your file has the wrong line endings (old Mac OS (`CR`) perhaps). If you have `dos2unix` you can try to convert them to Unix style line endings (`LF`).

Comment: Please see my comments about wc -l, also I'm using the right grep i.e /bin/grep

Comment: If you have dos2unix >= 7.1 you can check the line breaks.


$ dos2unix -i HxAcciCa.htm
     369     125       0  no_bom    text    HxAcciCa.htm


As I see it, the file has 369 DOS line breaks, 125 Unix line breaks, and 0 Mac line breaks. If you accidentally converted the file to Mac line breaks, use the mac2unix command to convert it back to Unix format

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a PC at the moment, but what could possibly help you troubleshoot:
1. Use grep --color -F to see if it matches correctly. 
2. After your statement, use | cat -A to see if there's any surprising control characters, lines should end in $, any other characters like \I or \M can sometimes be a headache.

I suspect number 2 as it seems to be Windows output. In which case you can cat filename | dos2unix | grep stmt should solve it

Did you save the dos2unix output as another file?
Just double check the file, it should be similar to this:

```
[root@pro-mon9001 ~]# cat -A Test.txt
Windows^M$
Style^M$
Files^M$
Are^M$
Hard ^M$
To ^M$
Parse^M$


[root@pro-mon9001 ~]# dos2unix Test.txt 
dos2unix: converting file Test.txt to Unix format ...

[root@pro-mon9001 ~]# cat -A Test.txt
Windows$
Style$
Files$
Are$
Hard$
To$
Parse$
```

Now it should parse properly - so just verify that it did convert the file properly
Good luck!

Comment: Since each line ends with a ^M does that mean that the format is mac??I've tried dos2unix but it didn't change anything.

Comment: ^M means carriage return, typical to Windows files. So maybe run dos2unix filename first to convert it to *nix style, then retry your statement. It is possible that dos2unix is not installed on your system as well, making the two-step process a good test

Comment: I did use dos2unix but that didn't help. the newline count is still 0.

Comment: Updated the answer - just that your ^M control characters are removes from the file